# Issue with unit test for tiny Flask app

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I have a very primitive Flask application which works as I'm expecting, but I'm failing to write a unit test for it. The code of the app is following (i omit insignificant part):

```
app.py

from flask import *
import random
import string

app = Flask(__name__)
keys = []
app.testing = True

@app.route('/keygen/api/keys', methods=['POST'])
def create():
    symbol = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    key = ''.join(random.choice(symbol) for _ in range(4))
    key_instance = {'key': key, 'is_used': False}
    keys.append(key_instance)

    return jsonify({'keys': keys}), 201
```

The test is:

```
tests.py

import unittest
from flask import *
import app

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_number_one(self):
        test_app = Flask(app)
        with test_app.test_client() as client:
            rv = client.post('/keygen/api/keys')

        ...something...

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The traceback:

```
ERROR: test_number_one (__main__.TestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 12, in test_number_one
    test_app = Flask(app)
  File "/Users/bulrathi/Yandex.Disk.localized/Virtualenvs/ailove/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 346, in __init__
    root_path=root_path)
  File "/Users/bulrathi/Yandex.Disk.localized/Virtualenvs/ailove/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 807, in __init__
    root_path = get_root_path(self.import_name)
  File "/Users/bulrathi/Yandex.Disk.localized/Virtualenvs/ailove/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 668, in get_root_path
    filepath = loader.get_filename(import_name)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 384, in _check_name_wrapper
ImportError: loader for app cannot handle <module 'app' from '/Users/bulrathi/Yandex.Disk.localized/Обучение/Code/Django practice/ailove/keygen/app.py'>

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: In your test, you're initialising `test_app` as `Flask(app)` when `app` is already an instance of `Flask`—essentially doing `test_app = Flask(Flask(app))`. Try removing this line and replacing the `with` line with `with app.test_client() as client:`.

Comment: I got `AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute 'test_client'`

Comment: You will need to add `app['TESTING'] = True` in your tests, too.

Comment: I got `TypeError: 'module' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't read the code correctly—if you change `import app` to `from app import app` (and remove `app['TESTING'] = True`; I see you already have it in `app.py`), things should work.

Comment: Thanks for help, my issue is solved!

Comment: Great! I'll add an actual answer to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few issues with the posted code (indentation aside):

First, in `tests.py` you `import app` and use it, but `app` is the module rather than the `app` object from `app.py`. You should import the actual `app` object using

```
from app import app
```

and secondly, you are using that `app` object (assuming we fix the import) as a parameter to another `Flask()` constructor—essentially saying:

```
app = Flask(Flask(app))
```

Since we've imported `app` from `app.py`, we can just use it directly, so we remove the `app = Flask(app)` line (and the associated `import` statement as we don't need it anymore) and your test file becomes:

```
import unittest
from app import app

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_number_one(self):
        with app.test_client() as client:
        rv = client.post('/keygen/api/keys')

    ...something...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

You should note also that the `from flask import *` form is discouraged in favour of importing specific parts of the module, so

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
```

would be better in your `app.py`.